# Images disappearing in firefox

Tags: jquery, css, swipe

I have a weird bug that has arisen just in Firefox. Using firebug it seems there is a bug or it doesn't like jQuery. When your in Firefox on the page listed below the images disappear. When you mouse over the pagination buttons the image will appear for a brief second and they re-disappear. They seem to blink. This bug is not present in chrome, IE, Safari, or Mobile applications. Currently only in Firefox. My Firefox version is 20.0.0.1.

**JavaScript being Included:**

JQuery, JQueryUI, BootStrap, Swipe, PrettyPhoto, Transit

The problen on this page is the product images being show in the center of the page. They appear when you mouse over the round circles with numbers, the pagination. partDivPics is the id tag where the images are placed.

Username: demo /
Password: demo

Link to Problem: (Try in firefox)
http://partspro.com/digital_catalog/catalog/item/Airaid/MXP/450-264

Style Sheet: (Fairly Well Documented)
http://partspro.com/digital_catalog/application/views/_common/css/style.css

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: Your server requires authentication so unless you give us username/password we can't see your page

Comment: i have added username and password. When you dont have to enter it on a regular basis your forget that its there :)

Comment: Sorry but it works smoothly on my firefox...Try clearing your cache. closing the firefox and restart again.

Comment: Didnt change anything. Its doing it for someone else in the office as well. What version of firefox are you using?

Comment: Any suggestions then? Its not working for me still after refreshes and browser cache has been reset

Comment: I still have not been able to resolve this problem. Its a weird one.